# How to define addition and multiplication by an scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Consider the set **S** which only element is "shoe"(**S** is a set that consists of a shoe) $S=\{shoe\}$. Let *F* be a field. Define in **S** the operations of addition and scalar product like

$shoe+shoe=shoe$ and $c(shoe)=shoe$ , c is an element of *F*.

I'm a little confused about this, the problem doesn't want me to prove anything but to define the addition and the scalar product, but where do i can start? Isn't defining an arbitrary thing?

Comment: actually because your set has only one element, there's only one possibility for the definition (if you think about it, this is isomorphic to the vector space containing only the zero vector)

Comment: Thank you, so is that analogous to the fact that vector 0 is unique? I'm still trying to define the addition but don't really know what axioms to use or give validity to the definition.

Comment: Addition on a set $S$ is by definition a function $\alpha:S \times S \to S$ (usually we write $+: S \times S \to S$). Since $S$ has only one element, there is only a single function you can define, namely $\alpha(\text{shoe}, \text{shoe}) := \text{shoe}$; or written in more common notation, $\text{shoe}+\text{shoe}:=\text{shoe}$. There's no need to use any axioms or anything to give validity to this definition. A definition is a definition; you can define anything you want as long as it is logical (which in this case it is); the nice thing here is that you only have 1 possible definition.

Comment: A similar story holds for defining scalar multiplication. Now, if you want to show further that $(S, +, \cdot)$ satisfies the axioms of a vector space, then you just check each of them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining operations, look at the established axioms for those operations, and make sure your definition respects them. As long as your definition of the operation respects those axioms, any operation you come up with is fair game.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i don't understand why $shoe+shoe=shoe$ and $c(shoe)=shoe$ .Is it because S has only one element?

Comment: It could be, it is only a definition after all. But, if we want the set S to have some other properties as to give it some structure it would make sense to define addition and scalar multiplication such that $c(shoe) \in S, \forall c \in F$ and $shoe + shoe \in S$

Comment: After reading the comment on your post, I've realized that if, and only if, $shoe$ is the null vector. S is, in fact, a vector space

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in the next exercise, i need to prove that $S$ is a vector-space. Why $S$ can't be one? If it has the addition and scalar multiplication defined, and is over a field *F*? Isn't that by definition a vector-space?

Comment: As I've stated above, if you consider $shoe$ to be the zero-vector, it is a vector space. I just hadn't realized it when I first wrote my comment.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to define the addition but i don't know which axioms can give validity to the definition, can i suppose that shoe is unique? Or can i prove it?